# vba - suming values based on multiple conditions

Tags: vba, excel, sum

I would like to write a function, which will sums values based on multiple criteria. Here is my attempt, but I realized, I cannot use same value multiple times for “case” procedure.

I could separate every sum value to different function, but I will need like 40 sums values.( 3 different categories of conditions, from every category sometimes you use one condition, sometimes multiple)
Do you have any better ideas or elegant solution?

Thank you

```
Function suma_data() As Variant
Dim row As Integer
row = 2
Dim returnVals(10) As Double
Dim all As Double
Dim voc As Double
Dim cvc As Double
Dim ms1 As Double
Dim ms2 As Double
Dim mv As Double
Dim metped As Double
Dim ssi As Double
Dim nsc As Double
Dim siov As Double


Sheets("data").Select
Do Until Sheets("data").Cells(row, 1).Value = ""
    Select Case Cells(row, 2).Value
        Case Is = "0922", "09604"
           all = all + Cells(row, 4)
        Case Is = "09223", "09224"
            voc = voc + Cells(row, 4)
        Case Is = "0950"
            cvc = cvc + Cells(row, 4)
        Case Is = "0113", "0980"
            If Cells(row, 3) = "00164381" Or Cells(row, 3) = "42137004" Then
                ms1 = ms1 + Cells(row, 4)
            End If
        Case Is = "0133", "0810", "0820"
            If Cells(row, 3) = "00164381" Then
                ms2 = ms2 + Cells(row, 4)
        Case Is = "0980"
            If Cells(row, 3) = "00151866" Then
                mv = mv + Cells(row, 4)
            End If
        Case Is = "0980"
            If Cells(row, 3) = "00164348" Or Cells(row, 3) = "30807506" Then
                metped = metped + Cells(row, 4)
            End If
        Case Is = "0980"
            If Cells(row, 3) = "31797857" Or Cells(row, 3) = "42134943" Then
                ssi = ssi + Cells(row, 4)
            End If
        Case Is = "0810", "0980"
            If Cells(row, 3) = "30853923" Then
                nsc = nsc + Cells(row, 4)
            End If
        Case Is = "0980"
            If Cells(row, 3) = "17314852" Then
                siov = siov + Cells(row, 4)
            End If

    End Select
    row = row + 1
Loop
returnVals(1) = all
returnVals(2) = voc
returnVals(3) = cvc
returnVals(4) = ms1
returnVals(5) = ms2
returnVals(6) = mv
returnVals(7) = metped
returnVals(8) = ssi
returnVals(9) = nsc
returnVals(10) = siov
suma_data = returnVals
End Function
```

Comment: Can't you use SUMIFS?

Comment: @SJR my thoughts too. A classic case where VBA is unnecessary and much slower than the inbuilt functions? See this link: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/11/12/excel-sumifs-sumif-multiple-criteria/

Comment: i should use that, but i wanted to know, how to do it differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by a more "**elegant solution**" you mean sucks less than: Yes, here is a more elegant solution.

The idea is to write a function that will take 1 to 3 conditions and return a value if a matching value is found for each condition in the corresponding categories else the function will return 0.

### getConditionalValue():Function

Returns a value if conditions are in Category values

```
Function getConditionalValue(value As Double, _
                             Optional Condition1 As String, Optional Category1 As Variant, _
                             Optional Condition2 As String, Optional Category2 As Variant, _
                             Optional Condition3 As String, Optional Category3 As Variant) As Double

    If Not IsMissing(Category1) Then If UBound(Filter(Category1, Condition1, True, vbBinaryCompare)) = -1 Then Exit Function
    If Not IsMissing(Category2) Then If UBound(Filter(Category2, Condition2, True, vbBinaryCompare)) = -1 Then Exit Function
    If Not IsMissing(Category3) Then If UBound(Filter(Category3, Condition3, True, vbBinaryCompare)) = -1 Then Exit Function

    getConditionalValue = value
End Function
```

### Refactored Loop

```
Do Until Sheets("data").Cells(row, 1).value = ""
    all = all + getConditionalValue(Cells(row, 4), Cells(row, 2).value, Array("0922", "09604"))

    voc = voc + getConditionalValue(Cells(row, 4), Cells(row, 2).value, Array("09223", "09224"))

    cvc = cvc + getConditionalValue(Cells(row, 4), Cells(row, 2).value, Array("0950"))

    ms1 = ms1 + getConditionalValue(Cells(row, 4), Cells(row, 2).value, Array("0113", "0980"), _
                                    Cells(row, 3), Array("00164381", "42137004"))

    ms2 = ms2 + getConditionalValue(Cells(row, 4), Cells(row, 2).value, Array("0133", "0810", "0820"), _
                                    Cells(row, 3), Array("00164381"))

    mv = mv + getConditionalValue(Cells(row, 4), Cells(row, 2).value, Array("0980"), _
                                  Cells(row, 3), Array("00151866"))

    metped = metped + getConditionalValue(Cells(row, 4), Cells(row, 2).value, Array("0980"), _
                                          Cells(row, 3), Array("00164348", "30807506"))

    ssi = ssi + getConditionalValue(Cells(row, 4), Cells(row, 2).value, Array("0980"), _
                                    Cells(row, 3), Array("31797857", "42134943"))

    nsc = nsc + getConditionalValue(Cells(row, 4), Cells(row, 2).value, Array("0810", "0980"), _
                                    Cells(row, 3), Array("30853923"))

    siov = siov + getConditionalValue(Cells(row, 4), Cells(row, 2).value, Array("0980"), _
                                      Cells(row, 3), Array("17314852"))
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Hope, I didn't miss any of your original conditions:

```
Select Case Cells(Row, 2)
Case "0922", "09604"
    all = all + Cells(Row, 4)
Case "09223", "09224"
    voc = voc + Cells(Row, 4)
Case "0950"
    cvc = cvc + Cells(Row, 4)
Case "0113"
    Select Case Cells(Row, 3)
       Case "00164381", "42137004"
          ms1 = ms1 + Cells(Row, 4)
       Case "00164381"
          ms2 = ms2 + Cells(Row, 4)
    End Select
Case "0980"
    Select Case Cells(Row, 3)
        Case "00164381", "42137004"
           ms1 = ms1 + Cells(Row, 4)
        Case "00151866"
           mv = mv + Cells(Row, 4)
        Case "00164348", "30807506"
            metped = metped + Cells(Row, 4)
        Case "31797857", "42134943"
            ssi = ssi + Cells(Row, 4)
        Case "30853923"
            nsc = nsc + Cells(Row, 4)
        Case "17314852"
           siov = siov + Cells(Row, 4)
    End Select
Case "0810"
    Select Case Cells(Row, 3)
        Case "00164381"
            ms2 = ms2 + Cells(Row, 4)
        Case "30853923"
            nsc = nsc + Cells(Row, 4)
        End Select
Case "0820"
    If Cells(Row, 3) = "00164381" Then
        ms2 = ms2 + Cells(Row, 4)
    End If
End Select
```